# Linq To Entities "Does not recognize the method" on deployment only

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code in EF 6.1.3 Code first.  That worked

```
public List<ReportSummary> FieldStatus() 
{
   return Context.stdReports
            .GroupBy(groupKey)
            .Select(g => new ReportSummary
            {
                PKi = g.Key.Id,
                Name = g.Key.Name,
                Sum = g.Sum(report => report.lng_premium),
                Count = g.Count(),
            })
            .OrderBy(summary => summary.Name)
            .ToList(); 
}
public class GroupKey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which has an issue on converting the Report Summary to SQL

```
 public class ReportSummary
{
    private string _pk;

    public string PK { get { return _pk;  } set { _pk = value; } }
    public int? PKi 
    {
        set {
            _pk = value != null ? value.ToString() : "";
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double? Sum { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

But this does not work when I push it to azure. (It actually operates normally and as expected locally).

The expected types for T are

- int
- string
- probably guid in the future. (but not at the time of testing)

This code does not work when deployed:

```
 public List<ReportSummary> FieldStatus() 
{
   return Context.stdReports
            .GroupBy(groupKey)
            .Select(g => new ReportSummary
            {
                PK = g.Key.Id.ToString(),
                Name = g.Key.Name,
                Sum = g.Sum(report => report.lng_premium),
                Count = g.Count(),
            })
            .OrderBy(summary => summary.Name)
            .ToList(); 
}
public class GroupKey<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Report Summary is the same on both versions.

Comment: What's the runtime type of `Context.stdReports` when running locally?

Comment: They are both executing against the same SQL Azure View

Comment: I got that from the question, but maybe the `Context` is instantiating slightly different classes in your development and deployment environments, for some reason?

Comment: Comes back as exactly the same typename

Comment: Please.. what "doesn't work"?

Comment: I get the "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
" error when trying to run this code (on Azure only, so debugging is dificult)

Comment: Can you reproduce the error locally by running a "Release" build?

Comment: are you running SQL Server locally? Can you try to run your code locally but point to SQL Azure?

Comment: The Sql server is in azure wether I run the c# code locally or in azure